# What happens when a member function with no arguments is called by an object in c++

Tags: c++, member-functions, this-pointer

Suppose we have a member function of `class X` and it is `X f()` which returns an object of `class X` and takes no arguments.

So if it is called by an object of `class X`, say `X obj` is the object.

So if we call `obj.f()`, so as per the C++ rules a secret argument is passed to the function `f()` and that is `this` pointer of the object which contains the address of the object which calls `f()`.

So my confusion is how it is managed by C++, because this means we can never have a member function in C++ with no arguments at all, because every time a secret argument would be passed.

For a function with an argument say `func(int a)`, it is actually a function which can take 2 arguments, where one of the arguments is the secret argument (`this` pointer) and the other is `int a`.

So what can we do if we strictly want a member function in C++ with no arguments at all (like in the case of an interrupt service routine)?

Please tell me if I am wrong or if I am missing some concept.

Comment: I d'ont really get why a hidden argument, that you don't bother to manage, could stop you from doing what you want

Comment: you can make a static method which will be called without "this" secret argument.

Comment: I've fixed up your question a little bit, but there are way too many `so`s in it, so you might want to rephrase it a little more. BTW, for cases such as ISR, you can simply declare `static void f()` inside `class X`. Please note that you'll need to return `void`, because an ISR should not return any value.

Comment: If you dislike object oriented programming, simply don't use it. If you have objects and your methods have to deal with their objects, you have to have a pointer to it. This is independent from the language you use. That is simply a requirement which is the base of object to member function relationship. And on the other hand, if you have no object but you want to write your functions and put it into classes only for cleaning up and separating your code domains, simply use static methods which are the same as functions but have the name space of the class. If so, you don't need a object.

Comment: @barak manos: thanks barak..for ISR i will need to return void,,but i can return anything for other cases ...right???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a [class function, aka a static member function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Class_methods).

It will have no implicit `this` pointer.

In C++, you can declare one with the `static` keyword:

```
class foo
{
public:
    static void bar();
};

void foo::bar()
{
    this; // error
}
```

Comment: Thanks zenith...this is actually what i was looking for...using static function would be ideal for this situation..

Comment: Without using static there will always be a this pointer passed to the function...

Comment: Yes, but always think carefully whether the function actually needs to be in a class, or should it be a free function altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean a static function like so;

```
class Object {
public:
    static void function() {}
};
```